# Cut in my tyre sidewall & tread depth?

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage

Is this small cut in my cars rear left side wall anything to worry about?

[image: Sidewall Damage]

Not only that but I’ve just purchased this car, and to me the tread looks very low and seems to be wearing unevenly.

[image: Tread]

Any help is appreciated as I don’t want to take any risks.

Comment: There's a number of questions about damages tires on the site already. Consider looking over [the results of this search](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btires%5D+cut) and see if any apply to your situation.

Comment: Tire health is off-topic. I vote to close.

Comment: Uneven wear is always due to suspension/alignment. Unless you have an AWD terrain it’s best to change a pair of tires. Pirelli has a reputable warranty program, depending on the tire age, discounts are applicable. From the pictures nothing significant is indicated, however  an inspection at a tire shop is necessary to validate the safety. Plus get the alignment done.

Answer (score 1):

Considering these are run flat tires, the little *scratch* on the sidewall is nothing. Run flats are able to work due to a reinforced sidewall. If the tire isn't losing air, there's no bulges, and it's not showing cords, there's a very good chance there's no issue with the tire.

As far as the tread goes, you really have to measure it to see what is going on. What I'm seeing in the picture you're showing seems to me to be a decent amount of tread left, though I have nothing to reference it against to tell for sure.

According to the [Kwik-Fit website](https://www.kwik-fit.com/tyres/information/uk-tyre-law), it states:

> UK law requires that your vehicle is fitted with the correct type and size of tyre for the vehicle type you are driving and for the purpose it is being used. ... The legal limit for minimum depth of the tread on your tyres is 1.6 millimetres, across the central ¾ of the tread around the complete circumference of the tyre.

I'd suggest as long as the tire depth is over the 1.6mm as stated, you're golden. In the picture I can believe your tires (if the rest look like what you've pictured) easily meet this specification.